# Display element in layout view base on existence of other element

Tags: bixby

Come after going through the solution for [How to check whether a text value content exists in a Bixby layout view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622409/how-to-check-whether-a-text-value-content-exists-in-a-bixby-layout-view).

My issues is on audio element, i will check for the existence of audioItem.duration before display their title one-by-one on a list. I had make sure on the debug console that some audio is with duration while some didn't. So i try on the result view with macro

```
content{
    if(exists(audioItem.duration)){ 
        thumbnail-card{
          image-url ("#{value(audioItem.albumArtUrl)}")
          title-area {
            slot1{
                text{
                    style(Title_XS)
                    value ("#{value(audioItem.title)}")
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }

}
```

It display empty but without that `if` it will display all of it without filter. How should i improve on the code?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not look wrong. In this case, the support team may need to view your code in its entirety in order to help you with this behavior.

I would recommend reaching out to the support team via the "Contact Support" option under the Help dropdown menu of Bixby Developer Studio.